# How do i prevent jsTree from expanding table cell?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am creating a jsTree inside a table cell.

The tree without expanding looks like this:

[image]

But when i click on any root node . It expands the table cell.

[image]

I want that table cell should not be expanded.

My code is as follows:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0"cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="margin-top:10px;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:5px;">PCA</td>
                    <td id="population"></td>
                    <td id="sex"></td>
                    <td id="literacy"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#population").jstree({ 

                    "html_data" : {
                        "data" : "<?php echo $populationdata;?>"
                    },
                    "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data","ui","checkbox" ]
                });
                $("#sex").jstree({ 

                    "html_data" : {
                        "data" : "<?php echo $sexdata;?>"
                    },
                    "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data","ui","checkbox" ]
                });
                 $("#literacy").jstree({ 

                    "html_data" : {
                        "data" : "<?php echo $literacydata;?>"
                    },
                    "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data","ui","checkbox" ]
                });

            });
        </script>
```

I thought to use overlay method for this i have made following changes

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0"cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="margin-top:10px;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:5px;">PCA</td>
                    <td><div id ="overlay"><div id="population"></div></div></td>
                    <td><div id ="overlay"><div id="sex"></div></div></td>
                    <td><div id ="overlay"><div id="literacy"></div></div></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

But now tree looks like this:

[image]

How do i resolve this issue?

Comment: What should it do then? How will you see the tree itself if the cells is not expanding?

Comment: Thanks balint for replying. The tree should be opened as an overlay

Comment: That is not really possible as you are trying to do it, as the root node of the tree (which is initially is the tree itself) is in the cell. So either the root is "not really in" the cell or it will expand. 
You wanted to use `absolute` position and not fixed I think. You can position the tree over the table with static positions and static cell widths and heights. That will solve your problem with a few more css rows.

Answer (score 0):

to prevent the table cell from expanding you need to apply a `style` attribute to the `div` containing the `jstree`.

Now your table would look like this

```
<div id ="overlay"><div id="population" style="overflow:auto;">
```

this would prevent the table cell from expanding, but provides a scroll bar if the space is insufficient.